# /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long with only 4 arguments

Tags: bash, awk

So I'm running a script I wrote for a language modeling task. On the "to_remove=" line, it errors out with "/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long" even though there's only 4 arguments

my code:

```
echo "Removing n-grams that contain a word with count < $min_count"
counts=`cat combined_counts`
to_remove=`awk -v c=$min_count '( NF == 2 && $NF < c ) {print $1}' combined_counts`
for unigram in $to_remove; do
    counts=`echo "$counts" | egrep -v "\b$unigram\s"`
done
echo "$counts" > combined_counts
```

output:

```
Removing n-grams that contain a word with count < 3
/home/likewise-open/AD/bherman/new_decoder/language_model/scripts/create_lm: line 210: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long
```

I've also tried replacing the troublesome line with:

```
awk -v c=$min_count '( NF == 2 && $NF < c ) {print $1}' combined_counts > unigrams_to_remove
```

But it gives the same error and the unigrams_to_remove file is empty.

The weirdest part is that, when i run the same code from the command line immediately afterwards (meaning the combined_counts file is unchanged), it doesn't error out.

```
AD\bherman@cluster4:~/new_decoder/language_model/working/filter_tests
$ min_count=3
AD\bherman@cluster4:~/new_decoder/language_model/working/filter_tests
$ to_remove=`awk -v c=$min_count '( NF == 2 && $NF < c ) {print $1}' combined_counts`
AD\bherman@cluster4:~/new_decoder/language_model/working/filter_tests
$ echo "$to_remove" | wc -l
15211
```

Comment: The number of arguments doesn't matter. The number of BYTES needed to represent the arguments AND THE SET OF ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES matters.

Comment: ...so, this is pretty much unanswerable without knowing both the length of bytes of your four arguments, *and* the length in bytes of your environment (try `cat /proc/self/environ | wc -c` to retrieve that latter number; normally, it'd be a useless use of cat, but `/proc` lies to `stat()`).

Comment: The size of the file doesn't matter for an argument list length limit. Are you sure that's line 210?

Comment: You might also want to check that `min_count` contains the value you expect it to. If it were a very large string rather than a number, well, there you are.

Comment: similarly, `bash -x yourscript` is your friend for seeing what's _actually_ being run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `min_count` is in the logged message right before the failure.

Comment: So it is. Environment variables, then. If someone's using `export` when they don't need to...

Comment: On a tangential note, capturing long lists in backquotes is a sure recipe for *actually* bumping into this error sooner or later. See if you couldn't keep the bulk of the data in a pipeline, and use shell variables only for small amounts of control data. (Should improve the code smell, too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "Removing n-grams that contain a word with count < $min_count"
awk -v c=$min_count '( NF == 2 && $NF < c ) {print}' combined_counts | 
grep -Fvxf - combined_counts > tmp 
mv tmp combined_counts
```

Edit:

**clearification**

The awk statement takes the desired lines to remove and outputs them to a file called to_remove (rather than storing it in a huge array).
The next line subtracts the lines from to_remove from combined_counts and stores it in a file called tmp.
The last line cleans up the extra files and stores the desired output to the original file.

Yes I know the `grep -Fvxf` command is really cool and allows minimal and elegant scripting :D

Edit2:
Cultivated the script further thanks to tripleee's comment!

Edit3:
fixed typo in script: changed "{print}" to "{print $1}"

Edit4:
fixed missing file argument for awk

Comment: Can you explain your answer? What was the problem, and what did you do to solve it?

Comment: @JohnKugelman: He removed the line where he assigns a huge file to a variable (`counts=$(<combined_counts)`).

Comment: This can be forther cultivated to avoid the first temporary file.  `awk '... stuff ...' | grep -Fxvf - combined_counts > tmp`

Comment: @tripleee So true, I'll edit right away. I'm still a beginning Linux user and I really appreciate the pointers, especially from a famous stack overflow contributor such as yourself (seriously, I see you posting quality answers all over the place)!

Comment: Worked perfectly with a few typo fixes and a very small change: instead of "grep -Fvxf" I used "grep -Fvwf". And you're right, that grep command is really cool :)

Comment: @TimeDelta Thanks for pointing out some inconsistencies! Note that changing `print` to `print $1` will not result in correct code though (only for lines consisting of one field). It should most definitely be `print` or `print $0`. `$0` resembles the entire line.

Comment: @ShellFish I don't want the entire line. The portion of the combined_counts file i'm interested in consists of "<word> <count>". I'm trying to remove every line in the file that contains a word with a count < a certain number. There are also lines that are e.g. "<word> ... <word> <count>" but I only want to remove the line if it contains a word that by itself has a count < a certain number.

Comment: @TimeDelta I understand but grep will match the lines of both files, if one file consists of less information the grep might fail. Anyway, if it works, it works :D

Answer (score 1):

The script you posted is 7 lines long, calls awk with 1 argument and CANNOT produce the error message you posted and you cannot reproduce the error running the isolated awk script from the command line.

The error message you posted:

```
/home/likewise-open/AD/bherman/new_decoder/language_model/scripts/create_lm: line 210: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long
```

is complaining about line 210 of some shell script that is invoking awk with too many arguments.

Therefore your problem is not with the script you showed us. If it's part of some larger script then look earlier in that script for a mismatched quote or something. You could start by commenting out parts of it until you can isolate the part that needs to exist for the error to be output.

Comment: I only posted part of the code for my script. I assure you though that line 210 is that awk line (I didn't feel it was prudent to copy 210 lines of code).

Comment: I understand but I'm telling you the problem is NOT with that line so it's somewhere else in your script in the 200 or so lines you haven't shown us. There's a SLIM possibility it's the `cat` immediately before the call to awk but I can't see how that could produce that specific error.